# listen() a socket on machine A and accept() it on machine B

Tags: windows, sockets

Can I listen() a socket on one machine (name it A) and accept() it on another machine (name it B)? Machine A and B will be on the same LAN and client will connect() througt the same public address, but this is not a must.

Comment: The question doesn't really make sense.  What are you actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

No. `accept` can only be called on a listening socket on the same system.

However, you can set up machine A to forward all the data to machine B, by connecting to it separately. xinetd provides a port-forwarding feature, for example (though to the best of my knowledge, xinetd is Unix-only).

Answer (score 1):

> Can I listen() a socket on one machine (name it A) and accept() it on another machine (name it B)?

No. The listening socket exists on machine A. It doesn't exist on machine B.

The question doesn't make sense.